# Encoding images for URI use

Tags: android, encoding, base64, decoding

I am busy with a small android app. The appplication connects to a WCF using restful that in turn connects to a database. The application does work. Now I want to send a Image to the database.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "sendImage/{seq}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string sendImage(string seq);
```

On the android application I encode a Image making use of BASE64.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.defaults);
textView.setText(encodedImage);
```

This encryption does work. The problem is that I now what to send the string `encodedImage` to the WCF to write to the database. Thus the string is passed in the URI.

```
"htp://_____.__/serv/ManagementSystem.svc/sendImage/" + encodedImage
```

The problem is that the string that I get from encoded contains `/` characters.

```
/9J/DASDFkFASDF/.....
```

This causes a problem in the URI as it picks up the `/` as a change of parameter, thus picking up that it is not a valid request. Is there a way to remove the `/` without compromising the decoding or is there a better way of converting a image to a string and back to an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the server side, I can at least think of two options:

1) After base64 encoding, replace all / with _, which is valid for url, has no particular pre-assigned meaning, and it is not used by base64. On the server side, you apply the opposite replace;

2) This is more straightforward that option 1, instead of get, you use put or post.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of doing option two. Has less overhead than option one.